# How to create a 2D array of objects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, object, dictionary, roguelike

I am creating a map for my roguelike game and already I stumbled on a problem. I want to create a two dimensional array of objects. In my previous C++ game I did this:

```
class tile; //found in another file.

tile theMap[MAP_WIDTH][MAP_HEIGHT];
```

I can't figure out how I should do this with Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

```
theMap = Array.new(MAP_HEIGHT) { Array.new(MAP_WIDTH) { Tile.new } }
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I call the objects functions in that array? I need to cycle through the array and call each objects draw -function.

Comment: @Shub: `theMap.each {|y| y.each {|x| x.draw } }`

Comment: @Adrian would `theMap.flatten.each {|x| x.draw}` work (I know it would be slow)?

Answer (score 3):

Use arrays of arrays.

```
board = [
 [ 1, 2, 3 ],
 [ 4, 5, 6 ]
]

x = Array.new(3){|i| Array.new(3){|j| i+j}}
```

Also look into the `Matrix` class:

```
require 'matrix'
Matrix.build(3,3){|i, j| i+j}
```

Comment: I am familiar with multidimensional arrays and matrices in general, my problem lies with not knowing how to declare one as an array of objects in ruby.

Comment: You don't need to declare things in Ruby, thanks to dynamic typing.

Comment: Note: Ruby >= 1.9.2 will only support rectangular matrices.
See: http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_2_rc1/NEWS

Comment: I guess I'm supposed create an object inside my 2D-array with .new() like Adrian showed me. That's cool and all, but what do I use to call an object that I didn't declare with any name? I must be stupid :(

Comment: Looks like theMap.each { |i| i.each { |j| j.function } } works. It's weird having the objects seperate from the array, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

2D arrays are no sweat

```
array = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
 => [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] 
array[0][0]
 => 1 
array.flatten
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 
array.transpose
 => [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

For loading 2D arrays try something like:

```
rows, cols = 2,3
mat = Array.new(rows) { Array.new(cols) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Let's define some class
class Foo
  # constructor
  def initialize(smthng)
    @print_me = smthng
  end
  def print
    puts @print_me
  end
# Now let's create 2×2 array with Foo objects
the_map = [
[Foo.new("Dark"), Foo.new("side")],
[Foo.new("of the"), Foo.new("spoon")] ]

# Now to call one of the object's methods just do something like
the_map[0][0].print # will print "Dark"
the_map[1][1].print # will print "spoon"
```